# Errors with chartjs after angular 7 to angular 8 migration

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have migrated my code from Angular 7 to Angular 8 in that process of migration i got some errors which i am not able to fix. Can anyone help me out on it.

The migration process went well but my application is not working after migration to angular 8.

Can anyone tell me what went wrong with the migration. As i am getting the errors mostly on the Chartjs part it seems. All other errors have been addressed.

Below are the errors i got.

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.44 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 145 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 462 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.09 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 86.1 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 2.29 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 329 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src/app/components/analytics/job-analytics/job-analytics.component.ts(36,5): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/analytics/job-analytics/job-analytics.component.ts(37,5): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/analytics/job-analytics/job-analytics.component.ts(38,5): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/analytics/job-analytics/job-analytics.component.ts(39,5): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/analytics/job-analytics/job-analytics.component.ts(544,13): error TS2322: Type '{ labels: any; datasets: { data: any; label: string; backgroundColor: string; borderColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; ... 5 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartData'.
  Types of property 'datasets' are incompatible.
    Type '{ data: any; label: string; backgroundColor: string; borderColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBorderColor: string; ... 4 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets[]'.
      Type '{ data: any; label: string; backgroundColor: string; borderColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBorderColor: string; ... 4 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets'.
        Types of property 'datalabels' are incompatible.
          Type '{ align: string; anchor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
            Types of property 'align' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | "left" | "right" | "start" | "center" | "end" | "top" | "bottom" | Align[] | ((context: Context) => Align)'.
src/app/components/analytics/job-analytics/job-analytics.component.ts(551,13): error TS2322: Type '{ labels: any; datasets: { data: any; label: string; borderColor: string; backgroundColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; ... 5 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartData'.
  Types of property 'datasets' are incompatible.
    Type '{ data: any; label: string; borderColor: string; backgroundColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBorderColor: string; ... 4 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets[]'.
      Type '{ data: any; label: string; borderColor: string; backgroundColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBorderColor: string; ... 4 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets'.
        Types of property 'datalabels' are incompatible.
          Type '{ align: string; anchor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
            Types of property 'align' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | "left" | "right" | "start" | "center" | "end" | "top" | "bottom" | Align[] | ((context: Context) => Align)'.
src/app/components/analytics/job-analytics/job-analytics.component.ts(558,13): error TS2322: Type '{ labels: any; datasets: { data: any; label: string; borderColor: string; backgroundColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; ... 5 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartData'.
  Types of property 'datasets' are incompatible.
    Type '{ data: any; label: string; borderColor: string; backgroundColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBorderColor: string; ... 4 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets[]'.
      Type '{ data: any; label: string; borderColor: string; backgroundColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBorderColor: string; ... 4 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets'.
        Types of property 'datalabels' are incompatible.
          Type '{ align: string; anchor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
            Types of property 'align' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | "left" | "right" | "start" | "center" | "end" | "top" | "bottom" | Align[] | ((context: Context) => Align)'.
src/app/components/analytics/job-analytics/job-analytics.component.ts(565,13): error TS2322: Type '{ labels: any; datasets: { data: any; label: string; borderColor: string; backgroundColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; ... 5 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartData'.
  Types of property 'datasets' are incompatible.
    Type '{ data: any; label: string; borderColor: string; backgroundColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBorderColor: string; ... 4 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets[]'.
      Type '{ data: any; label: string; borderColor: string; backgroundColor: string; pointBorderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBackgroundColor: string; pointHoverBorderColor: string; ... 4 more ...; datalabels: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets'.
        Types of property 'datalabels' are incompatible.
          Type '{ align: string; anchor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
            Types of property 'align' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | "left" | "right" | "start" | "center" | "end" | "top" | "bottom" | Align[] | ((context: Context) => Align)'.
src/app/components/analytics/run-history/run-history.component.ts(42,3): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/analytics/run-history/run-history.component.ts(43,3): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/analytics/run-history/run-history.component.ts(44,3): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/coverage/api-coverage/api-coverage.component.ts(152,15): error TS2322: Type '(context: Context) => string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | (string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)[] | ((context: Context) => string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)'.
  Type '(context: Context) => string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type '(context: Context) => string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
    Type 'string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
        Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
src/app/components/coverage/api-coverage/api-coverage.component.ts(195,15): error TS2322: Type '(context: Context) => string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | (string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)[] | ((context: Context) => string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)'.
  Type '(context: Context) => string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type '(context: Context) => string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
    Type 'string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
        Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
src/app/components/coverage/api-coverage/api-coverage.component.ts(238,15): error TS2322: Type '(context: Context) => string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | (string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)[] | ((context: Context) => string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)'.
  Type '(context: Context) => string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type '(context: Context) => string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
    Type 'string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
        Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
src/app/components/dialogs/testsuit-edit-dialog/testsuit-edit-dialog.component.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
src/app/components/dialogs/xss-filter-dialog/xss-filter-dialog.component.ts(9,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/src/render3'.
src/app/components/issues/issues-edit/issues-edit.component.ts(14,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
src/app/components/projects/project-recommendations/project-recommendations.component.ts(20,50): error TS2305: Module '"E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Label'.
src/app/components/projects/project-recommendations/project-recommendations.component.ts(20,57): error TS2305: Module '"E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Color'.
src/app/components/projects/project-recommendations/project-recommendations.component.ts(77,12): error TS2322: Type '{ responsive: true; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions & { annotation: any; }'.
  Property 'annotation' is missing in type '{ responsive: true; }' but required in type '{ annotation: any; }'.
src/app/components/projects/project-recommendations/project-recommendations.component.ts(81,12): error TS2322: Type '{ scales: { yAxes: { ticks: { beginAtZero: true; }; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions & { annotation: any; }'.
  Property 'annotation' is missing in type '{ scales: { yAxes: { ticks: { beginAtZero: true; }; }[]; }; }' but required in type '{ annotation: any; }'.
src/app/components/projects/projects-config/projects-config.component.ts(41,50): error TS2305: Module '"E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Label'.
src/app/components/projects/projects-config/projects-config.component.ts(41,57): error TS2305: Module '"E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Color'.
src/app/components/projects/projects-config/projects-config.component.ts(41,63): error TS2305: Module '"E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'borderColor'.
src/app/components/projects/projects-config/projects-config.component.ts(167,14): error TS2322: Type '{ responsive: true; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions & { annotation: any; }'.
  Property 'annotation' is missing in type '{ responsive: true; }' but required in type '{ annotation: any; }'.
src/app/components/projects/projects-config/projects-config.component.ts(171,14): error TS2322: Type '{ scales: { xAxes: { display: true; scaleLabel: { display: true; labelString: string; }; }[]; yAxes: { display: true; ticks: { beginAtZero: true; callback: (value: any) => any; }; scaleLabel: { display: true; labelString: string; }; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions & { annotation: any; }'.
  Property 'annotation' is missing in type '{ scales: { xAxes: { display: true; scaleLabel: { display: true; labelString: string; }; }[]; yAxes: { display: true; ticks: { beginAtZero: true; callback: (value: any) => any; }; scaleLabel: { display: true; labelString: string; }; }[]; }; }' but required in type '{ annotation: any; }'.
src/app/components/run-detail/run-detail.component.ts(17,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/animations/browser/src/render/shared'.
src/app/components/run-list/run-list.component.ts(48,3): error TS2740: Type 'undefined[]' is missing the following properties from type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")': config, data, destroy, update, and 13 more.
src/app/components/run-list/run-list.component.ts(49,3): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/run-list/run-list.component.ts(50,3): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/run-list/run-list.component.ts(51,3): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'import("E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")'.
src/app/components/testsuites/test-suite-list/test-suite-list.component.ts(23,50): error TS2305: Module '"E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Label'.
src/app/components/testsuites/test-suite-list/test-suite-list.component.ts(23,57): error TS2305: Module '"E:/ng72ng8/Fxt/Web/src/main/ui/material/node_modules/@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Color'.
src/app/components/testsuites/test-suite-list/test-suite-list.component.ts(100,16): error TS2322: Type '{ scales: { xAxes: { display: true; scaleLabel: { display: true; labelString: string; }; }[]; yAxes: { display: true; ticks: { beginAtZero: true; callback: (value: any) => any; }; scaleLabel: { display: true; labelString: string; }; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions & { annotation: any; }'.
  Property 'annotation' is missing in type '{ scales: { xAxes: { display: true; scaleLabel: { display: true; labelString: string; }; }[]; yAxes: { display: true; ticks: { beginAtZero: true; callback: (value: any) => any; }; scaleLabel: { display: true; labelString: string; }; }[]; }; }' but required in type '{ annotation: any; }'.
src/app/components/vulnerability-dashboard/vulnerability-dashboard.component.ts(87,25): error TS2322: Type '(context: Context) => string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | (string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)[] | ((context: Context) => string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern)'.
  Type '(context: Context) => string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type '(context: Context) => string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
    Type 'string | string[] | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern | ChartColor[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern'.
        Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```